# create csv from objects with different keys

Tags: javascript, csv

I have an array of objects. Some of their keys are identical but some of them exist only in one of the object:

```
const data =[
{id:123, name:foo, number:25},
{id:124, name:boo, number:35, blue:8},
{id:125, name:soo, number:40, red:10}
]
```

I want to convert my data into a CSV, so that the headers will include all keys. if key doesn't exists in the object its value should be null , see example below:

| id | name | number | blue | red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | foo | 25 | null | null |
| 124 | boo | 35 | 8 | null |
| 125 | soo | 40 | null | 10 |

I was able to achieve this with few loops , but the code is ugly :)

Thanks!

Comment: ``I was able to achieve this with few loops`` so what is your question here ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this solution applies to your problem.

[Generate a csv file from a javascript array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396943/generate-a-csv-file-from-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

If you have any doubts in the process, just reply here. I'll try to help